# ¿Cómo conectar MySQL a ODBC, corriendo MySQL en Ubuntu VirtualBox?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows, virtualbox, odbc

tengo MySQL ejecutándose en VirtualBox.

quiero hacer una conexión atreves de ODBC, pero siempre recibo un error de conexión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se exactamente que debo configurar en Ubuntu corriendo desde VirtualBox para poderme conectar desde Windows.

agradecería sus ayudas y guías.

Comment: Si MySQL está en una máquina virtual el host no puede ser localhost. Tiene que ser la IP de la VM.  Tienes que configurar la VM para que use una IP de tu red local.

Comment: Si ya lo pude configurar, gracias. En el IP debía poner la IP de mi máquina virtual.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).

Comment: aunque la publicación es sobre la conexión de MySQL; el problema esta enfocado a la configuración de tu entorno; y no realmente a un problema de programación o desarrollo.